# How do I call a object's member function as a unary_function for std algorithms?

Tags: c++, stl

I have a class that looks like this.

```
class A 
{
public:
    void doSomething();
}
```

I have an array of these classes. I want to call doSomething() on each item in the array. What's the easiest way to do this using the algorithms header?

Comment: bradtgmurray: you asked and answered your own question, both "about 3 hours ago", with no intervening answers?  BAD FORM.   I am down-voting.

Comment: @abelenky, you need to read the FAQ.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use std::mem_fun_ref to wrap the member function as a unary function.

```
#include <algoritm>
#include <functional>

std::vector<A> the_vector;

...

std::for_each(the_vector.begin(), the_vector.end(),
              std::mem_fun_ref(&A::doSomething));
```

You can also use std::mem_fun if your vector contains pointers to the class, rather than the objects themselves.

```
std::vector<A*> the_vector;

...

std::for_each(the_vector.begin(), the_vector.end(),
              std::mem_fun(&A::doSomething));
```

Comment: To be accurate, in your second example, the vector doesn't contain references, but objects/instances. The 'ref' in mem_fun_ref indicates that the method will be converted to a function that takes as parameter a reference to an instance. With mem_fun, the function takes a pointer.

Comment: Effective STL  is your friend -- READ IT